# I'm trying to save an array from subdocuments inside other subdocument but it does not

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, mongoose, subdocument

Im trying to save this, but mongoose does not. This is the api, model and what the console show me.

```
newExam = async (req, res)=>{
    hasItUsernameTwo(req,res)
    const user = await User.findById(req.user),
    examData = JSON.parse(req.body.deepFormJSON),
    newExam = new Exam();
    console.log(examData)
    console.log(examData)
    newExam.title = examData.title
    newExam.description = examData.description
    newExam.author = user.username
    newExam.questions = []
    // para crear el array de objetos con preguntas
    if(Array.isArray(examData.questions.question)){
        examData.questions.question.forEach(e => {
            newExam.questions.push({
                question: e,
            })
        })
        for (var i = 0; i < examData.questions.question; i++) {
            newExam.questions[i].answers = []
        }
    } {
        newExam.questions.push({
            question: examData.questions.question
        })
        newExam.questions.answers = []
    }
    // para crear el array con las respuestas de cada pregunta
    // const get = examData.questions.answers.answer.forEach(async (e, i, array) => {
    //     if(Array.isArray(examData.questions.question)){
    //         newExam.questions[i].answers.push({answer: e})
    //     } {
    //         newExam.questions.answers.push({answer: e})
    //     }
    //     // return newExam.save()
    // });
    // await Promise.all(get)
    for (const [i, e] of examData.questions.answers.answer.entries()){
        if(Array.isArray(examData.questions.question)){
            newExam.questions[i].answers.push({answer: e})
            newExam.questions[i].markModified("answers")
        } {
            newExam.questions.answers.push({answer: e})
            newExam.markModified("answers")
        }
    }
    // for (const [i, e] of examData.questions.answers.correct.entries()){
    //     if(Array.isArray(examData.questions.question)){
    //         for(const [index, element] of newExam.questions[i].answers.entries()){

    //         }
    //     } {
    //         for(const [index, element] of newExam.questions.answers.entries()){

    //         }
    //     }

    // }
    console.log(newExam.questions.answers)
    // para crear el array con los valores buleanos de cada pregunta
    // await newExam.save();
    // await newExam.validate();
    // user.exams.push(newExam._id)
    // await user.save()
    console.log(newExam)
    // res.redirect(`exams/${newExam._id}`)
    res.redirect(`/`)
}
```

This is my model:

```
answerSchema = new Schema({
    answer: String,
    correct: String
}),

questionsSchema = new Schema({
    question: {
        type: String,
        required: "The questions are required"
    },
    answers: [answerSchema]
}),

examSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }, 
    author: { 
        type: String, 
        ref: "User",
        required: `The author is required.`
    },
    questions: [questionsSchema],
    usersDone: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId, 
        ref: "User",
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});
```

And this is what the console show me

```
{
  title: 'JavaScript',
  description: 'An Exam For JavaScript Users',
  questions: { question: 'What is JavaScript?', answers: { answer: [Array] } }
}
[
  { answer: 'An extension for Java' },
  { answer: 'A programming language' },
  { answer: 'Idk, but it has 14 million of users' },
  { answer: 'The Snake Game' }
]
{
  usersDone: [],
  _id: 60fa9b14ac5f133b70fa2ded,
  questions: [
    {
      _id: 60fa9b14ac5f133b70fa2dee,
      question: 'What is JavaScript?',
      answers: []
    }
  ],
  title: 'JavaScript',
  description: 'An Exam For JavaScript Users',
  author: 'AlejandroArellano'
}
```

I have tried to solve this a multiple times but it does not save the answers! I have checked out on my database on mongo, and it does not appaer there!!!!

Comment: all you `.save()` are commented out. You need to save to update the data

Comment: When i execute that, it does not save as i want

Comment: Can you please add what it is saving and what you want it to be ? @AlejandroJesúsArellano

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code snippet [here](https://pastebin.com/aiHuKS9M) for readability.

In line 42,you made a block (`{}`) after the end of if block, without any `else` or `if` or anything, I am not sure it's the cause but worth looking into it

In line 43, you are modifying `newExam.questions.answers` but in line 44, you are marking `newExam.answers` as modified. I guess you are marking the wrong sub-document as modified. Try to rectify and let me know if it is fixed (or not!).